# In Lua need to separate the string based on backslash through Regex

Tags: lua

I have a String like 
`file:c:\test\xyz.exe`
how can I separate the above string in 3 parts through Regex in Lua?

For the example, the first part would be `file:`,
the second part of string should be `c:\test`
and the third part of string should be `yz.exe`.

Comment: input string is       file:c:\test\xyz.exe

Comment: expected out three string in LUA through Regex

Comment: file: will be in first string

Comment: c:\test\ will be in  second string

Comment: xyz.exe will be in third string

Comment: @vic: Why do you spam comments? You can just edit your question...

Comment: I fixed the question's formatting and spelling of Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the String manipulation part of the Lua manual : http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4

In particular match() and gmatch(). For example :

```
 s = "file:c:\\test\\xyz.exe"
 for first, second, third in string.gmatch(s, "(%a+):(.+)\\([%a%p]+)") do
   print(first)
   print(second)
   print(third)
 end
```

To allow alphanumerical character in the first and third place, replace `%a` with `%w`. All others possible pattern are referenced at the end of the linked manual chapter.

You must double each '\' in your input string, otherwise pattern matching won't work. Backslash is an escaping character in Lua, so if you want to have one in your string, you must escape it : `"\\"`

The given code will work for "file:c:\test\xyz.exe" and "file:C:\test\test3\a\abc.exe"

Comment: here issue is my input string keep on varying like

Comment: it can be like file:C:\test\test3\a\abc.exe

Comment: basically I need executable name string and the folder path in a string

Comment: and in a string there can be multiple backslash

Comment: that is the reason through regex is the best way to do it

Comment: I updated my answer... And FYI, you can edit your comment to add more informations, there's no need to post 5 time.

Comment: thanks  Krtek  your solution is perfect. If my string would have been like  "file32:c:\test\xyz.exe" or "file64:C:\test\test3\a\abc.exe"  how would it work in thaT CASE i AM SORRY i HAVE NOT PUT IT IN FIRST CASE ITSELF

Comment: If you have numbers in the first part, you must replace %a by %w (alphanumerical character). Don't forget to double '\', otherwise it won't work. Don't forget to accept the right answer